# JWT works in developer console but does not working in APEX code

Tags: namedcredentials, jwt

In Salesforce when I use a JWT Named Credential from developer console it is successful but running from the same APEX code from a Visual Force Page or Lightning Component it is not successful.  I am logged as a System Administrator user when running both tests.

Running the APEX code from developer console returns status **200** and the log shows the Header Authorization set:

```
HTTP Header Authorization=Method: Bearer - Authorization Credential Hash: -418822787
```

Running the APEX code from a Visual Force Page or Lightning Component returns status **400** and the log shows the Header Authorization not set:

```
HTTP Header Authorization=Not Set
```

**APEX CODE:**

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setEndpoint('callout:CUCredential?cursor=1&maxRecords=15&detailLevel=5&prospectId=');

req.setMethod('GET');

Http http = new Http();

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

**NAMED CREDENTIAL:**

```
URL: https://test.zenmonics.com/cu-connect/Acct/Appl/Search

Certificate: zencert

Identity Type: Named Principal

Authentication Protocol: JWT

Issuer: SalesForce

Named Principal Subject: CUSystemCreds

Audiences: https://test.zenmonics.com/cu-connect/Acct/Appl/Search

Token Valid for 10 Minutes

JWT Signing Certificate: zencert

Generate Authorization Header: checked
```

Can someone please help on what needs to be done to get the code to be able to run in APEX.

Thanks,

Don

Comment: what do you mean by `when I use a JWT Named Credential from developer console `?  Are you executing apex code from the DC and it works but not when you run it as part of some other transaction?

Comment: I changed the description above.  I am running the same APEX code show above in Developer Console and as part of a Lightning component and getting the results shown above.

Comment: What version is the class?

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem.  It was set to version 40.  I changed it to 46 and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Apex Code works in Developer Console but the identical code does not when executed as part of a transaction, the most likely cause is that your class is running at an earlier version.

Developer Console anonymous Apex always runs in the org's version.

Named Credentials appeared in Summer 16, [JWT Named Credentials appeared in Summer 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_security_more_auth_protocols.htm).  So, your class needs to be at V46 or higher.